# EventGhost - detect exit of EventGhost

Tags: automation

EventGhost ("EG") has a useful *Autostart* feature which executes user defined commands on its start-up. Is there way to implement a *Autoexit*? What event is triggered when EG is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For startup, the Event is:

```
Main.OnInit
```

For exit:

```
Main.OnClose
```